# Please how can I fix invalid credentials issue in terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

The following error was displayed on the command line when I ran terraform plan with the following code.

```
Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: resources.ProvidersClient#List: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/61230797-2385-4403-8a23-553c4a8da920/providers?api-version=2016-02-01": dial tcp: lookup management.azure.com on 172.31.192.1:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
```

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  client_id = "bd330f5d-****-****-****-************"
  client_secret = "VDa8Q~****-****~kzb-************h~****-2"
  tenant_id = "cfd11325-****-****-****-dd495c0916ae"
  subscription_id = "61230797-****-****-****-************"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myTFResourceGroup"
  location = "westus2"
}
```

Comment: any chance to set `TF_LOG=trace` to get more logs detail? which privileges owns your app at the subscription level? Which DNS settings have been configured on the VM where you run TF plan (could you try setting them to 8.8.8.8?) ?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision the resources using my credentials and I was able execute the code successfully.

Here the error mentioned might cause due to the multiple reasons which end up not provisioning the resource as per the requirement.

1. Verify Credentials: Double-check the credentials you are using to authenticate with Azure. Make sure you have the correct client ID, client secret, and tenant ID. Also, ensure that the credentials have the necessary permissions to access the Resource Manager API.

### [image]

[image]

---

[image]

Make sure all these values don't have any typo mistakes.

2. Check Service Principal Permissions: Confirm that the service principal associated with the credentials has the required permissions. The service principal needs the "Owner" or "Contributor" role on the subscription to access and manage resources.

[image]

Make sure you're provided with necessary roles like i mention above to have access to provision the resource you wish for.

3. Since you're using command line interface make sure you have installed the latest version of it.

By following all the steps mentioned above use the code as you mentioned in the query with updated IDs and credentials.

My **main.tf** goes as follows

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

 subscription_id = ""
  client_id       = ""
  tenant_id       = ""
  client_secret   = ""

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myTFResourceGroupvk"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

Output:

While doing `terraform_apply`

[image]

By following all the steps, we will be able to provision the resources we need to.

Comment: Thanks @vinaykumarbolli-mt please I followed your instructions and the error still persists.
Is it possible to discuss over a call session?

Comment: Thanks @vinaykumarbolli-mt please I followed your instructions and the error still persists.
Is it possible to discuss over a call session?

Comment: As you mentioned, in query you got the issue while executing terraform plan.

Along with the steps I mentioned in the Answer if the issue still persists 

Please provide me the info below

1. Provide me the Info you got while running terraform init.
2. Please share me the info related to access level you had in your subscription.

Comment: Thanks @vinaykumarbolli-mt for the detailed and helpful information. Please, it works after setting the DNS to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @PoppaDynasty my pleasure! if my comment has been useful, please, like it in order to identify it as a solution!